# Negate these statements and then reexpress the results as equivalent positive statements

Tags: logic

1. $$\forall a\in A,\exists b\in B:a\in C\iff b\in C.$$
2. $$\forall y>0,\exists x:y=ax^2+bx+c.$$

I can't get passed the first step on how to negate these statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > The first step is to use the equivalence between : $\lnot \forall$ and $\exists \lnot$ and between : $\lnot \exists$ and $\forall \lnot$.

For 1) we have to "unwind" $P \Leftrightarrow Q$ as $(P \Rightarrow Q) \land (Q \Rightarrow P)$.

Thus for 1) :

> $\lnot [∀a \in A ∃b \in B (a \in C \Leftrightarrow b \in C)]$

we have :

$∃a \in A ∀b \in B \lnot [(a \in C \Rightarrow b \in C) \land (b \in C \Rightarrow a \in C)]$

and using De Morgan :

$∃a \in A ∀b \in B [\lnot (a \in C \Rightarrow b \in C) \lor \lnot (b \in C \Rightarrow a \in C)]$.

Now we can use another equivalence, between $P \Rightarrow Q$ and $\lnot P \lor Q$ and De Morgan again, to "move inside" the negations :

> $∃a \in A ∀b \in B [(a \in C \land b \notin C) \lor (b \in C \land a \notin C)]$.

*Note* : a bi-conditional means that the two sentences are both true or both false; thus, its negations means that if one is true the other is false, and viceversa.

---

For 2) :

> $\lnot [∀y > 0 ∃x (ax^2 + bx +c = y)]$

we have :

$∃y > 0 ∀x \lnot (ax^2 + bx +c = y)$

i.e.

> $∃y > 0 ∀x (ax^2 + bx +c \ne y)$.

Comment: That was extremely helpful and made a lot of sense. Thank you so much!!